# How Receieve Validation Errors In Java Android Spring

Tags: java, android, spring, api, android-asynctask

I am sending API requests to a backend API using Spring in Android (Java). My question is how to receive validation errors to the error handler at ex 400 bad request response. Here is my code:

```
 class RestTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ResponseEntity<ExpectedReturn>>
    {
        protected ResponseEntity<ExpectedReturn> doInBackground(String... uri)
        {
            try{
                final String url = uri[0];
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.setErrorHandler(subscriber.getErrorHandler());
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                // set authentication tokens:
                ResponseEntity<ExpectedReturn> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,callMethod,httpEntity, expectedReturnClass);
                return response;
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<ExpectedReturn> result) {
            if(result !=null && result.getBody() !=null)
            {
                subscriber.getSubscriber().onComplete(result.getBody(),result.getStatusCode());
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is, if the post data fails validation (is incorrect), the API will return as JSON error object with errors, ex:
[image]

In case of a validation error, the error handler is called with a ClientHttpResponse object as a parameter. Calling the response.getBody() returns an InputStream.  My question is, is there any way of receiving an object mapped from the JSON error response (as shown above) to the error handler, or perhaps converting the input stream to something readable (like a hashmap) so I can display the errors returned by the API (ex: "Name is required" etc...)?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use this library for sending request to server? If not, consider using Retrofit and Okhttp which are the standard set of tools for networking in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code and in case of a *400 bad request* the catch block receives an instance of `HttpClientErrorException` which has a method to get the error body as String:

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final String url = "https://reqres.in/api/login";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            //Same result with restTemplate.exchange() too
            return restTemplate.postForObject(url, "{\n" +
                    "    \"email\": \"peter@klaven\"\n" +
                    "}", String.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            if (e instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
                String responseBodyAsString = ((HttpClientErrorException) e).getResponseBodyAsString();
                Log.e(TAG, "Validation error" + responseBodyAsString);
                //You can parse this with gson or jackson here
                return responseBodyAsString;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute() called with: result = [" + result + "]");
    }

}
```

Which prints in:

```
W/RestTemplate: POST request for "https://reqres.in/api/login" resulted in 
400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
E/MainActivity: 400 Bad Request
E/MainActivity: Validation error{"error":"Missing email or username"}
D/MainActivity: onPostExecute() called with: result = [{"error":"Missing email or username"}]
```

If you want to use the none default error handler and set your custom error handler you can get the error message as string this way:

```
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                    return response.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError();
                }

                @Override
                public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                    String errorResponse = new String(getResponseBody(response), getCharset(response).name());
                    Log.e(TAG, "handleError: called with: " + errorResponse);
                }
            });

private byte[] getResponseBody(ClientHttpResponse response) {
    try {
        InputStream responseBody = response.getBody();
        if (responseBody != null) {
            return FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(responseBody);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // ignore
    }
    return new byte[0];
}

private Charset getCharset(ClientHttpResponse response) {
    HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
    MediaType contentType = headers.getContentType();
    return contentType != null ? contentType.getCharSet() : Charset.defaultCharset();
}
```

Then you can use Jackson or Gson to parse the error response as below:

```
new Gson().fromJson(responseBodyAsString, ExpectedResponse.class);
```

Note I've just did the same thing as implemented in `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`

**Edit:**
The whole `AsyncTask` and Spring Android APIs are so outdated, Here is the same example with Retrofit:

```
        api.login(new BodyModel("peter@klaven"))
            .enqueue(new Callback<ExpectedModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ExpectedModel> call, @NonNull Response<ExpectedModel> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        //Do what you got to do
                    } else {
                        Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorModel> converter = MainActivity.this.retrofit.responseBodyConverter(ErrorModel.class, new Annotation[0]);
                        ErrorModel errorModel = null;
                        try {
                            errorModel = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorModel.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ExpectedModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
```

You can find the full [gist in my github repo](https://gist.github.com/MRezaNasirloo/70be5f34166bef60f99b8c93093bf4ad)

Comment: Thanks... Seems to work, but looks very hacky with the conversion... I was hoping for a more formally conventional way of doing it.. Are there any built-in features in spring resttemplate to do this?  How would the same example look like in something like retrofit?

Comment: @DanielValland No spring resttemplate can't do this any better, I've edited my post take a look for retrofit sample.

Comment: Reza  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DanielValland Any time ;)

Comment: Reza  Just for clarity, in your retrofit example, retrofit handles threads on it's own, such that the call does not hang the main thread? thanks.

Comment: @DanielValland Yup, It can handle it on its own, There is an option to execute it on the current thread with the `call.execute()` method too.

Comment: @DanielValland By the way if you think I answered your question, you can click on the award bounty icon next to my answer. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Will do, but have to wait 4 hours for some reason... :)

Comment: @DanielValland Ok :) I forgot to share this, you can learn more about retrofit here: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely be making a switch to retrofit. RestTemplate worked great until i got to error handling, and got really messy from there.. hehe